# Magento 2: Adding "updated_at" column does not update current time stamp

Tags: magento2, database

I am using Magento 2.2.6 version. Am just trying to add an extra column **updated_at**  in setup/upgradeschema.php. But on saving data, it is not updating the timestamp automatically. It is null always. Here is my code,

```
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
                'updated_at',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE],
                'Updated At'
            );
```

Adding the above code in

> setup/InstallSchema.php

or

> in upgradeschema[But only on creating the whole new table]

works fine. Can someone help?

Answer (score 5):

We have to empty the field updated_at after every changes in beforeSave function

```
public function beforeSave()
{
    if ($this->hasDataChanges()) {
        $this->setUpdateTime(null);
    }

    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all the file name should be `UpgradeSchema.php` and in that file you need have a check like

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '<your_module_version>') < 0) { //your code }
```

Secondly you need to increment the module version in `etc/module.xml` and then run the `bin/magento setup:upgrade`
Now you can see your column is updated in the database.
If so, then you can see updated time in the column.

Answer (score 0):

I think because your `default` key using Uppercase, try change your code to be like this :

```
...
->addColumn(
        'updated_at',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
        null,
        ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE],
        'Updated At'
...
```

if it does not work, you can see this link for more reference :

[How do auto add datetime in InstallSchema magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84255/how-do-auto-add-datetime-in-installschema-magento2)

Comment: I tried giving 'DEFAULT' in lowercase too but doesn't work. I will edit my question to change 'DEFAULT' in lowercase.

Comment: try to run `bin/magento cache:flush` in command line , if it still does not work I think you can try to follow this way https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84255/how-do-auto-add-datetime-in-installschema-magento2#answer-84269

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
->addColumn(
            'update_datetime',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
            null,
            [],
            'Modification Date Time'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to update the created_at and update_at columns on saving the data in the table.

1. Create created_at and update_at columns in the database table.

`................. <column xsi:type="timestamp" name="created_at" on_update="false" nullable="false" default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" comment="Creation Time"/> <column xsi:type="timestamp" name="updated_at" on_update="true" nullable="false" default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" comment="Update Time"/> .................`

2. Update the Model/CustomTable.php file to add `beforeSave()` function.

```
use Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper;
class CustomTable extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime
     */
    private $dateTime;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateTime,
        DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->dateTime = $dateTime;
        $this->dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;
        parent::__construct(....);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare data to be saved to database.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function beforeSave()
    {
        parent::beforeSave();
        if ($this->isObjectNew() && !$this->getCreatedAt()) {
            $this->setCreatedAt($this->dateTime->formatDate(true));
        }
        $this->setUpdatedAt($this->dateTime->formatDate(true));

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Hope this works for you.